# Datasets of Oil&Gas/electrical industry machinery for fault detection systems

Tags: data-request, industry

I'm going to start my degree thesis and I want to do a fault detection system using machine learning techniques. I need datasets for my thesis but I don't know where I can get that data. I'm looking for historical operation/maintenance/fault datasets of any kind of machine in the oil&gas industry (Drills, steam injectors, etc) or electrical companies (transformers, generators, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an interesting project With tons of data available. It's a real data benchmark executed over an industrial valve. This is the website.

[Industrial Actuator Real Data Benchmark Study.](http://diag.mchtr.pw.edu.pl/damadics/)